# Clickable element inside <a> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a React application.

I have a sort of card with image, title and a button to do stuff.

This is a simplified version:

```
<a href="www.example.com" class="card">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <div class="image">...</div>
        <div class="cta-button" onClick={handleOnClick}>cta</div>
    </div>
    <div class="title">title</div>
</a>
```

`cta-button` is placed on bottom-right of `image-wrapper` using `position: absolute`.

How can I, when clicking on `cta-button`, prevent visiting `card` link in `handleOnClick`?

Comment: Why are you putting a "button" inside a link?

Comment: An `<a>` shouldn't really contain a button in the first place, you might be able to work around it, but why not just wrap just the image in the link? (And maybe the title as well if required)

Answer (score 0):

Having an interactive element within an `a` element is a violation of the specification. [An `a` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) cannot have [interactive content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#interactive-content-2). While your `div` is just a `div` and so it's not interactive by default, it *is* interactive if you add a `click` handler to it. I suggest moving the clickable element *outside* the `a` element.

But if you want to have the invalid structure, you need to prevent the default action of the click. Have `handleClick` accept its `event` parameter and call `event.preventDefault()` on it:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = () => {
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        console.log("Stopped");
        e.preventDefault();
    };
    return <a href="https://stackoverflow.com"><div onClick={handleClick}>Click here</div></a>;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

For completeness, here's that same snippet with `stopPropgation` instead (which doesn't work):

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = () => {
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        console.log("Stopped");
        e.stopPropagation(); // Doesn't work
    };
    return <a href="https://stackoverflow.com"><div onClick={handleClick}>Click here</div></a>;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```